# Copying mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a web service application built using NodeJS. I am using mongodb as database.
The whole thing is in another system(A) in the network. Now I need to copy all the data to the mongodb database in my system(B).
Can anyone tell me the whole procedure in detail, like even from where I should execute the commands also. I am a beginner and have very little knowledge about mongodb.

Comment: google for exporting db of mongodb.. and then import ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `db.cloneDatabase()` command for that ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/#clone-a-database)).

1. Start the `mongo` shell from the command line on the destination server by running: `mongo`
2. Identify the name of the database to copy: `use name`
3. Copy the database from the source server: `db.cloneDatabase("1.2.3.4")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` utility.